# Serialize vs. Json

Tags: json, serialization

Now i am creating Ajax app and i want to know what is better to connect server data with client.

Last time i used json but some time ago i hear that serialized data is faster.

Who know what is better?

Comment: JSON is a serialization format. Can you be more specific?

Comment: i know that PHP is faster with serialized data than with json but whats about js?

Comment: Serialized into _what_? In can be serialized into JSON, XML a binary format and others.

Comment: JSON *IS* javascript. It's text-ified version of javascript data structures and is essentially "native" javascript code.

Comment: it's example of php's serialized data: a:5:{s:4:"host";s:9:"localhost";s:4:"user";s:4:"root";s:8:"password";s:0:"";s:8:"database";s:4:"opto";s:6:"prefix";s:5:"opto_";}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, a serialized binary representation will be smaller than a JSON representation of the same object (that in turn would be smaller than an XML representation).

In this regards, network transfers would be faster.

Comment: i find http://phpjs.org/functions/serialize:508 and http://phpjs.org/functions/unserialize:571 but i want to know this functions or json will be better?

Comment: @user568975 - You need to be more specific about "better". Better how? For what uses? And be aware that normally many times "better" depends on specifics - the best thing you can do is benchmark both approaches with _your_ code and see which one is better for your application.

Comment: Thanx, Oded! In my meaning better == faster.

Comment: @user568975 - faster to serialize? Deserialize? Transfer? Store?

Comment: @user568975 - Good question. You should benchmark deserialization using the different approaches with your objects. The result should tell you which one is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're comparing serialize (working similarly in PHP) and json on your client (a browser). There's a serialize function (similar to how PHP works) in jquery but no native unserialize. I suggest you work with json when communication is between your server and your client (ajax).